# how to set record_sample_rate for sip call when setting record_session in parameter of "bridge" on freeswitch diaplan?

Tags: call, sip, freeswitch

How to set record_sample_rate for sip call when set record_session in parameter of "bridge" on freeswitch diaplan:

```
<action application="bridge" data="{sip_cid_type=rpid,execute_on_answer='record_session /call-record/${sip_call_id}.wav'}sofia/gateway/demo_callout/$1"/>
```

Currently record_sample_rate value = 16000.
I tried `<action application="set" data="record_sample_rate=8000" />` but not working.
Hope to receive help.